# Total not adding up

Tags: java, string, if-statement, while-loop

I'm working on a classwork in high school comp sci class
and i have come across this problem.
the total is not adding.
can someone tell me why?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TimeSheets {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String loc;
    String[] day = new String[7];       
    String time1;
    String time2;
    int location;
    double total = 0;
    int num = 1;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    double clock1 = 0;
    double clock2 = 0;
    double hour;

    loc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your Work Location");
    location = Integer.parseInt(loc);

    while (x < 7 && y < 7) {

      day[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Day "+num+" 's Starting code");
      day[y] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Day "+num+" 's Ending code");
      time1 = day[x];
      time2 = day[y];

      if (time1 == "1") {
        clock1 = 9;
      }
      if (time1 == "2") {
        clock1 = 9.5;
      }
      if (time1 == "3") {
        clock1 = 10;
      }
      if (time1 == "4") {
        clock1 = 10.5;
      }
      if (time1 == "5") {
        clock1 = 11;
      }
      if (time1 == "6") {
        clock1 = 11.5;
      }
      if (time1 == "7") {
        clock1 = 12;
      }
      if (time1 == "8") {
        clock1 = 12.5;
      }
      if (time1 == "9") {
        clock1 = 13;
      }
      if (time1 == "A") {
        clock1 = 13.5;
      }
      if (time1 == "B") {
        clock1 = 14;
      }
      if (time1 == "C") {
        clock1 = 14.5;
      }
      if (time1 == "D") {
        clock1 = 15;
      }
      if (time1 == "E") {
        clock1 = 15.5;
      }
      if (time1 == "F") {
        clock1 = 16;
      }
      if (time1 == "G") {
        clock1 = 16.5;
      }
      if (time1 == "H") {
        clock1 = 17;
      }

      if (time2 == "1") {
        clock2 = 9;
      }
      if (time2 == "2") {
        clock2 = 9.5;
      }
      if (time2 == "3") {
        clock2 = 10;
      }
      if (time2 == "4") {
        clock2 = 10.5;
      }
      if (time2 == "5") {
        clock2 = 11;
      }
      if (time2 == "6") {
        clock2 = 11.5;
      }
      if (time2 == "7") {
        clock2 = 12;
      }
      if (time2 == "8") {
        clock2 = 12.5;
      }
      if (time2 == "9") {
        clock2 = 13;
      }
      if (time2 == "A") {
        clock2 = 13.5;
      }
      if (time2 == "B") {
        clock2 = 14;
      }
      if (time2 == "C") {
        clock2 = 14.5;
      }
      if (time2 == "D") {
        clock2 = 15;
      }
      if (time2 == "E") {
        clock2 = 15.5;
      }
      if (time2 == "F") {
        clock2 = 16;
      }
      if (time2 == "G") {
        clock2 = 16.5;
      }
      if (time2 == "H") {
        clock2 = 17;
      }

      hour = clock2 - clock1;
      total = hour + hour;

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "total hour" + total);
      x++;
      y++;
      num++;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to figure that out by using the debugger.

Comment: Why don't you refactor using a static map? this would require one initialization and make the computation slightly faster/neater

Answer (score 4):

check string equality with equals() method. `==` operator checks if two reference variables refer to the same string object. `equals()` method check if two strings are meaningfully equal.

```
    if (time1 == "1") {
```

sholud be

```
    if (time1.equals("1")) {
```

and also all your other `if`'statements. I strongly advise you to make use of nested-if else rather than a million if statements.Like:

```
if (time1.equals("1")) {
        clock1 = 9;
      }
      else if (time1.equals("2")) {
        clock1 = 9.5;
      }
    ..........
```

Comment: I strongly advise computing the value, or at the least making use of a Map to derive these values

Comment: i changed it to 

if (time1.equals("1")) {


but it still doesn't work.
i never learn static map before.
but i just did a quick google and it seem very nice.
i will try it out

Answer (score 1):

**Use this approach for static map using ENUM**

```
public enum TimeToClock{
    1(9),
    2(9.5);
    //so on

    public final double value;

    private static final Map<Integer,TimeToClock> map;
    public static final TimeToClock[] VALUES = values();
    static {
        map = new HashMap<Integer,TimeToClock>(3);
        for (TimeToClock type : VALUES) {
            map.put(type.value, type);
        }
    }   

    TimeToClock(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }   
    public double getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    public static TimeToClock get(int key){
        return map.get(key);
    }
}
```

**Use:**

```
double value = TimeToClock.get(2).getValue();
```

Comment: Thats a better implementation in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Your total at the end looks like it's worked out incorrectly.

```
total = hour + hour;
```

Would it not make more sense to be...

```
total = total + hour;
```

So you are incrementing the total rather than just resetting it after each loop iteration?