# Enumbody error how can i fix it?

Tags: java, enums

I was working on a school homework, and discovered such thing called Enum.

and i thought it was pretty helpful to my homework.

so i decided to use it, but when then this error showed up.

i googled stuff about it, but i cant seem to fix it.

the error "insert enumbody to complete compilation unit" showed up at the number 15

```
public enum TimeToClock {   

    9,9.5,
    10,10.5,
    11,11.5,
    12,12.5,
    13,13.5,
    14,14.5,
    15,15.5,
    16,16.5,
    17. 

}
```

This is an attempt to improve the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685434/total-not-adding-up)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by putting all those numbers inside the body of an enum?

Comment: This is not the use of enum that you are probably looking for. Please specify clearly what you want?

Comment: is the enum complete or is that `17.` incomplete? That can be causing the error

Comment: this was my previous post you can see my code there.
i thought the code would be neater without the nested if statements by using enum. 
so when user input "1" they will get 9. 
if they input "2" they will get 9.5.
etc etc

Comment: @user1872886 Looking at the code from your previous question, I don't think enums are the best solution.  Instead, build a [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) from codes to time values.  Create a `HashMap<String,Double>`, then add all of your code mappings (e.g. `map.put("1",9.0)`).  Then, you can just do `clock1 = map.get(time1);`.

Answer (score 3):

I would use an array of double.

```
static final double[] timeToClock = {
    9,  9.5,
    10, 10.5,
    11, 11.5,
    12, 12.5,
    13, 13.5,
    14, 14.5,
    15, 15.5,
    16, 16.5,
    17
};
```

or a List as @Puce suggests with

```
static final List<Double> timeToClock = Arrays.asList(
    9,  9.5,
    10, 10.5,
    11, 11.5,
    12, 12.5,
    13, 13.5,
    14, 14.5,
    15, 15.5,
    16, 16.5,
    17
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the concept of enum is not used to just store a set of constants but a set of constants which means something to you but are actually instances of your enum, so storing floats directly doesn't work.

Every number you insert must have a legal Java variable name such as:

```
public enum TimeToClock {
  _9(9.0f),
  _9_5(9,5f)
  ;

  public final float value;

  public TimeToClock(float value) {
    this.value = value
  }
}
```

In this way you can refer to your fields with `_9.value` and I guess this is the only way you can use the enum for your specific purpose. For anything else you can use:

- an array `float[] values = new float[]{9f, 9.5f, .... };`
- constants such as `public static final float _9_5 = 9.5f`

Using an enum is senseful if you can associate a meaning to every number, in your situation you can still use it without problems by having static compile check on the set of values allowed but as you can see syntax is quite clumsy because every value is just a value.

Answer (score 1):

Enum constants should be appropriate variable names and in Java a variable name cannot start with a number. You can try this maybe:

```
public enum TimeToClock {    
  T9, T9_5,
  T10, T10_5
  // Go on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Integers are not directly allowed within `enum` since Integers have no meaning by themselves.

Most people would use a `String`s' `array`, as it is the most simple way to achieve your goal.

However, imagine if you want to pass a schedule to a method parameter like this:

```
public void pronounceSchedule(String schedule){
   // Nothing ensures that a valid Schedule is passed !
}
```

With an enum, you would get the expected guarantee:

```
public void pronounceSchedule(TimeToClock timeToClock){
   // No need to validate the schedule since it is already assumed to be valid thanks to the compiler.
}
```

You could use:

```
public enum TimeToClock {
    NINE(9),
    NINE_AND_HALF(9.5f);
    // etc...

    TimeToClock(float schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
    }

    public float getSchedule(){
        return schedule;
    }

    private float schedule;
}
```

By the way, both methods are valid, really depending of your context and goal.